# Ranking update issue

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this code, its gives the output of the Database, now I want to order it with respect to `TeamPoints`. The team with higher points gets the first position. How do I Implement it.

I have been trying to add a `TeamRank` field in the Database, which updates a team Rank by increment or decrement. But it's not working so I decided to just order them by points, but now I am facing issues in arranging them in increasing order.

```php
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("", "", ", "");

    // Check connection:
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    mysqli_query($con,"CREATE VIEW Rankings AS
        SELECT TeamID, TeamName, TeamLeader, TeamEmail, P_1, P_2, P_3, P_4, P_5, S_1, S_2, TeamWins, TeamLoss, TeamPoints
        FROM team
        WHERE TeamID>0");

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM team");

    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th>TeamID</th>
        <th>TeamName</th>
        <th>TeamLeader</th>
        <th>TeamEmail</th>
        <th>Player #1</th>
        <th>Player #2</th>
        <th>Player #3</th>
        <th>Player #4</th>
        <th>Player #5</th>
        <th>Subsitute #1</th>
        <th>Subsitute #2</th>
        <th>Total Wins</th>
        <th>Total Losses</th>
        <th>Total Points</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['TeamID'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['TeamName'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['TeamLeader'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['TeamEmail'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['P_1'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['P_2'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['P_3'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['P_4'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['P_5'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['S_1'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['S_2'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['TeamWins'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['TeamLoss'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['TeamPoints'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: 1. Normalize your data

Comment: Yea I just did, now I have 1 Database with team information as TeamID Primary key, where as other has team rank information with TeamRank as primary key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a rank to the select and outputting it, along with limiting the output to a page (of 10 - easily changed):-

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("", "", "", "");

    // Check connection:
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $PageStart = 10 * intval($_POST['page']);

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT TeamID,
                                TeamName,
                                TeamLeader,
                                TeamEmail,
                                P_1,
                                P_2,
                                P_3,
                                P_4,
                                P_5,
                                S_1,
                                S_2,
                                TeamWins,
                                TeamLoss,
                                TeamPoints,
                                TeamRnk
                                FROM
                                (
                                    SELECT TeamID,
                                            TeamName,
                                            TeamLeader,
                                            TeamEmail,
                                            P_1,
                                            P_2,
                                            P_3,
                                            P_4,
                                            P_5,
                                            S_1,
                                            S_2,
                                            TeamWins,
                                            TeamLoss,
                                            TeamPoints,
                                            @Rank := @Rank + 1 AS TeamRnk
                                    FROM SomeTable
                                    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Rank:=0) Sub0
                                    ORDER BY TeamPoints DESC
                                ) Sub1
                                LIMIT $PageStart, 10");

    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th>TeamRnk</th>
        <th>TeamID</th>
        <th>TeamName</th>
        <th>TeamLeader</th>
        <th>TeamEmail</th>
        <th>Player #1</th>
        <th>Player #2</th>
        <th>Player #3</th>
        <th>Player #4</th>
        <th>Player #5</th>
        <th>Subsitute #1</th>
        <th>Subsitute #2</th>
        <th>Total Wins</th>
        <th>Total Losses</th>
        <th>Total Points</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['TeamRnk'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['TeamID'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['TeamName'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['TeamLeader'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['TeamEmail'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['P_1'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['P_2'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['P_3'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['P_4'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['P_5'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['S_1'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['S_2'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['TeamWins'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['TeamLoss'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['TeamPoints'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: I think there's an issue with systax, im getting this error
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\teamrankingdb\rank.php on line 69

Comment: Minor typo (forgot to give the subquery an alias). Try now

Comment: Thanks dude, PROBLEM SOLVED!!

btw I was thinking to create another table with teamrank information how do I modify this to add another table with TeamWins TeamLoss TeamRank and TeamPoints

Comment: Problem with a separate table with the rank in it is keeping it up to date. While you can have wins / losses / points in another table it doesn't really save you anything over having it in the main table (there would be a 1 to 1 relationship between the tables). In theory you should just have the results for each match and calculate the fields. However having these fields is useful and is a reasonable level of denormalisation. If you did keep them on a separate table just add an INNER JOIN to that table within the sub query (ie, before the CROSS JOIN).

Answer (score 1):

Is this what your looking for?

```
SELECT  TeamID,TeamName,TeamLeader,TeamEmail,P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4,P_5,S_1,S_2,TeamWins,TeamLoss,TeamPoints
FROM team
where TeamID>0
ORDER BY TeamPoints DESC;
```

Comment: Yea I tried implementing this but I am having issues getting output in a PHP table ..

Answer (score 0):

```
    CREATE VIEW Rankings AS
    SELECT  TeamID
         , TeamName
         , TeamLeader
         , TeamEmail
         , P_1        -- none 
         , P_2        -- of
         , P_3        -- these
         , P_4        -- belong
         , P_5        -- in a 
         , S_1        -- teams
         , S_2        -- table
         , TeamWins   -- and even
         , TeamLoss   -- these are
         , TeamPoints -- questionable
      FROM team
     where TeamID > 0;
```

Comment: P_1 to P_5 are players, where S_1 and S_2 are substitute's

Comment: I know. See normalization.